# Unresponsive script error in all browsers

Tags: jquery, browser

I am really annoyed with this unresponsive script error, here is my code

```
function changeTextAdd(id)
{

    $(".awp_class_horizantal span").html('');
    $(".awp_class_horizantal").click(function() {
            changeTextAdd(this.id);
        });
    $(".awp_class_vertical span").html('');
    $(".awp_class_vertical").click(function() {
            changeTextAdd(this.id);
        });
    $(".awp_class_vertical2 span").html('');
    $(".awp_class_vertical2").click(function() {
            changeTextAdd(this.id);
        });

    for(var i=0; i<addtionalspanIds.length;i++)
    {

        if($("#"+addtionalspanIds[i]+"_txt").val().length > 0)
        {    
            // console.log(addtionalspanIds[i]+"if");
            $("#"+addtionalspanIds[i]+' span').html($("#"+addtionalspanIds[i]+"_txt").val());
        }else {
            // console.log(addtionalspanIds[i]+"else");
            $("#"+addtionalspanIds[i]+' span').html('');
        }
    }
    var defaultValue = '';
    if($("#"+id+"_txt").val().length > 0){        
        defaultValue = "<option value='"+$("#"+id+"_txt").val()+"'>"+$("#"+id+"_txt").val()+"</option>";
    }
    $('#'+id+' span').html("<select id='"+id+"_spanSelectBox' class='spanSelectBox' name='span1' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px;z-index:1000;'>"+defaultValue+"<option value=''>--select--</option><option value='Wall panel'>Wall panel</option><option value='DRAPE'>DRAPE</option></select>");

    $("#"+id).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
    $(".spanSelectBox").on('change', whenSpanSelectChangedAdd);
}
```

I am calling this function on click on some span. Those span tags are in for loop in another function. In firefox it is showing that the unresponsive script is jquery-1.7.1.min.js. Why it is pointing to jquery library?

This is the loop form which am calling the above function

```
for(var i=1; i<=sidewalls; i++)
{
    for(var j=1; j<=backwalls; j++)
    {
        ////////////////////// First Row in the diagram ///////////////////
        //console.log(i+"  "+j);
        if((i == 1 && j < backwalls))
        {

            var countVer = count++;

            var newDiv = "<span class='add_droppable_span_class' id='add_droppable"+i+""+j+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px; height:"+(cellHeight-2)+"px;display:inline-block;margin:0px;padding:1px;float:left;'><span class='awp_class_vertical' id='awp_span_"+countVer+"' style=' height:"+(cellHeight-2)+"px;'  onclick='changeTextAdd(this.id);'><span style='position:relative; top:40%; white-space: nowrap; left:-9px;'></span></span></span><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countVer+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countVer+"_txt'>";
            $("#inner_div_addtional").append(newDiv);
        }                        
        ////////////////////// Second Row except last block  ///////////////////
        else if(i > 1 && j < backwalls && i != sidewalls) 
        {
            var countHor = count++;
            var countVer = count++;
            var newDiv = "<span class='add_droppable_span_class' id='add_droppable"+i+""+j+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px; height:"+(cellHeight-2)+"px;display:inline-block;margin:0px;padding:1px;float:left;'><span class='awp_class_horizantal' id='awp_span_"+countHor+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px;'    onclick='changeTextAdd(this.id);'><span></span></span><span class='awp_class_vertical2' id='awp_span_"+countVer+"' style=' height:"+(cellHeight-2)+"px;'  onclick='changeTextAdd(this.id);'><span style='position:relative; top:40%; white-space: nowrap; left:-9px;'></span></span></span><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countHor+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countHor+"_txt'><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countVer+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countVer+"_txt'>";

            $("#inner_div_addtional").append(newDiv);
        }else if(i == sidewalls && j < backwalls) ///////// Last Row except last block//////////////
        {
            var countHor = count++;
            var countHor2 = count++;
            var countVer = count++;
            var newDiv = "<span class='add_droppable_span_class' id='add_droppable"+i+""+j+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px; height:"+(cellHeight-2)+"px;display:inline-block;margin:0px;padding:1px;float:left;'><span class='awp_class_horizantal' id='awp_span_"+countHor+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px;'    onclick='changeTextAdd(this.id);'><span></span></span><span class='awp_class_vertical2' id='awp_span_"+countVer+"' style=' height:"+(cellHeight-2)+"px;'  onclick='changeTextAdd(this.id);'><span style='position:relative; top:40%; white-space: nowrap; left:-9px;'></span></span><span class='awp_class_horizantal' id='awp_span_"+countHor2+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px;top:-19px;' onclick='changeTextAdd(this.id);'><span></span></span></span><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countHor+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countHor+"_txt'><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countVer+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countVer+"_txt'><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countHor2+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countHor2+"_txt'>";
            $("#inner_div_addtional").append(newDiv);
        }
        ////////////////////// Starting From Second row all last blocks ///////////////////
        else if((i > 1 && j == backwalls) && (i != sidewalls))
        {
            var countHor = count++;
            var countVer = count++;
            var newDiv = "<span class='add_droppable_span_class' id='add_droppable"+i+""+j+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px; height:"+(cellHeight-2)+"px;display:inline-block;margin:0px;padding:1px;float:left;'><span class='awp_class_horizantal' id='awp_span_"+countHor+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px;'    onclick='changeTextAdd(this.id);'><span></span></span></span><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countHor+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countHor+"_txt'><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countVer+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countVer+"_txt'>";
            $("#inner_div_addtional").append(newDiv);
        }else if(i == sidewalls && j == backwalls) ///////// Last Row Last Block//////////////
        {
            var countHor = count++;
            var countHor2 = count++;
            var countVer = count++;
            var newDiv = "<span class='add_droppable_span_class' id='add_droppable"+i+""+j+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px; height:"+(cellHeight-2)+"px;display:inline-block;margin:0px;padding:1px;float:left;'><span class='awp_class_horizantal' id='awp_span_"+countHor+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px;'    onclick='changeTextAdd(this.id);'><span></span></span><span class='awp_class_horizantal' id='awp_span_"+countHor2+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px;top:"+(cellHeight-19)+"px;' onclick='changeTextAdd(this.id);'><span></span></span></span><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countHor+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countHor+"_txt'><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countVer+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countVer+"_txt'><input type='hidden' name='awp_span_"+countHor2+"_txt' id='awp_span_"+countHor2+"_txt'>";
            $("#inner_div_addtional").append(newDiv);
        }                    
        else
        {
            var newDiv = "<span id='add_droppable"+i+""+j+"' style='width:"+(cellWidth-2)+"px; height:"+(cellHeight-2)+"px;display:inline-block;margin:0px;padding:1px;float:left;'></span><input type='hidden' name='add_droppable"+i+""+j+"_txt' id='add_droppable"+i+""+j+"_txt'>";
            $("#inner_div_addtional").append(newDiv);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's going on here - it's not clear where some of your loop variables are coming from. A couple of things I'd recommend: 1. your loop checks should be cached rather than checking the length of something. Are you certain that whatever it is you're checking the length of isn't increasing because of something happening in the loop? 2. Avoid doing DOM manipulation in loops. Build your markup outside of loops and modify it in one action. This is a sure-fire way to kill performance in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had used the RECURSION here..

The function `changeTextAdd` is called by itself at the line of

```
$(".awp_class_horizantal span").html('');
$(".awp_class_horizantal").click(function() 
{
    changeTextAdd(this.id); // Here is your Recursion of the same function 
});
```

And the click event Handler is Rebound Infinitely inside the function.. Please check and go through about "Recursions"

Comment: Thank u for ur valuable advice.. could you pls suggest me how to call the function in my case???

Comment: Please shorten your Question.. and code.. Just Ask what is the actual point of problem. go through it..